# Why is the accuracy of the object detection model converted to tflite decreased by 20%

Tags: object-detection, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

When I train the mobilenet_v2_ssd model and convert it to a tflite model and run it on the coral edge TPU, the accuracy of the model drops by 20%.

I checked the detection results and found that in most cases the IOU of the detection frame and the label frame became smaller when the target was small. Compared with the unquantized model, the detection frame has a larger shift.

I guess it is due to the quantification that caused the regression offset of the target detection frame, but I cannot prove this point.

But when I try to enlarge the test picture, I found that the detection accuracy has not improved.

Why is the target detection regression result shifted after the model is converted to tflite? Do you have a good idea?

Comment: may i know what version of the tf object detection API are you using?
With tf1.x object detection api, you should do quantization aware training and the `.tflite` model should relatively be similar to the `.pb`. With tf2.x we are still looking into a tons of issue so I suggest not using it for now

Comment: @NamVu I am using version 1.12.0

Comment: @NamVu And I use the tflite_convert command line to convert the model.

Comment: Can you paste the full command as well as the training pipeline config?

Comment: @NamVu Excuse me, how does quantization aware training transform the model into tfilte? Do you use the tflite_convert command? Is the tflite_convert command a post-training quantization method? I am a bit confused, thanks!

Comment: Quantization aware training doesn't turn a model to tflite, you have to convert it. 
The `tflite_convert` command can be use to converts a quantized model to tflite.
How about you follow a full tutorial to see how it works? 
https://github.com/Namburger/edgetpu-ssdlite-mobiledet-retrain